# Java insert an element before and after a specific index

Tags: java, arraylist, insert

My Code:

```
ArrayList<CellNode> updateSubTour(ArrayList<CellNode> subTour, ArrayList<CellNode> fromTo){
        int i = subTour.indexOf(fromTo.get(0));
        ArrayList<CellNode> leftTour = subTour.clone();
        ArrayList<CellNode> rightTour = subTour.clone();
        leftTour.add(leftfromI,fromTo.get(1);
        rigthTour.add(rightfromI,fromTo.get(1);
        shorterTour = compare(rigthTour.distance,leftTour.distance)
        return shorterTour;
    }
```

fromTo is a kind of Pair, the first Element is the element in the subTour and the second one is the one I want to insert.

I have an element in subTour, I am going to find the Index with the indexOf function.
Now I need to insert an element [fromTo.get(1)] left from i and right from i.

I didn't found a solution to insert the element without overwriting the other elements.

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean by "insert an element [fromTo.get(1)] left from i and right from i"? Is `subTour` intended to be modified or do you need a new list returned?

Comment: Im going to compare the right and the left - distance and the shorter one is going to be the new subTour

Answer (score 2):

Your example needs some cleaning up but I believe I follow what you are asking for. Suppose you had a `List l` with some element `E` in the list at location `i` and you want to add object `O` to the list. By doing `l.add(i, O)`, `O` will be inserted before `E`. Doing `l.add(i+1, O)` will insert `O` after `E`.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that if you do the "before" add first, you'll need to do `l.add(i+2,O)` to insert `O` after `E` (because the first `add` will move the index of `E` to `i+1`).

Comment: True, but in this case, the insertions before and after are done to two different list instances.